# startAnimatingWithImagesInRange is not completing

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I need to animate series of images.

```
// Animate Circle
let duration = 1.0
circleGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("arc")
circleGroup.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 100), duration: duration, repeatCount: 0)
```

[image: gif animation shows animated circle which animates from 0% to 45% of its radius]

I have 101 images. From *arc0* to *arc100.*

[image: Xcode screenshot with images in the folder.]

Storyboard:

[image: storyboard with the watch app UI]

As you can see on the gif, my problem is that animation doesn't make full circle trip. Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried to set `duration` bigger?

Comment: yes, setting longer `duration` makes its slower but it still is not complete and ends at the same spot.

Comment: what is a `circleGroup` type?

Comment: `WKInterfaceGroup`

Comment: Try this @borisy circleGroup.setBackgroundImageNamed("arc")
    circleGroup.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(0,100), duration:1.0, repeatCount: 0)

Comment: @krishh, thanks but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like animation is stopping right after 40%. I opened asset library and renamed every file to the exactly same name. Then I opened my Git client and I saw this changes:

[image]

Animation now works. As you can see, problem was in a file name, it had extra space in it.

Also I learned that when doing backward animation `location` becomes not the starting point but the destination.